# ¿Cómo evitar que se modifique un Raycast cuando toco con 2 dedos en la pantalla?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un proyecto en Unity 3D 5.1. El problema que tengo es que cuando toco la pantalla con 2 dedos, modifica mi Raycast; pero si solo toco con 1 dedo, funciona bien. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto para que cuando toque la pantalla con 2 dedos no modifique el Raycast?

Comment: ¿Puede que no estés usando Input.GetTouch para acceder a los dedos por separado?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones:

1. utilizar `Input.GetTouch(0)` en vez de `Input.MousePosition`
2. Si lo que tratas es de detectar cuando se pulsa encima de un objeto, añadirle un Collider y utilizar, `OnPointerDown`, `OnPointerUp`, ...
3. Desactivar el multitouch utilizando `Input.multiTouchEnabled=false;`